# Right to left chart legend in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, arabic, hebrew

I want to use excel for right-to-left language
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling excel in the appropriate language. When switching language in excel the layout will not be changed only the language itself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Already done, it would be better if there is a VBA code to get this job done.

Comment: True, but the issue resolved after reinstalling in the new language? I had the same issue few years ago to use a Excell learning package we got on our schools.

I had Excell in English but it needed to be Dutch for the program to run. after fully deletion of the Microsoft office packages and reinstallation I got it to work.

Yes, It would be easier for end users if you could change language and it's settings within the Office packages.

On my work I encountered many problems with office packages, where business people came with their computer related issues.

Hope you got it working.